# Would I lose my chances of getting into Google if I ask for 2.5 months to prepare for an interview? (SWE College Grad)

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, student, scheduling

I was asked to do a second round of phone interview since the first one didn't go well enough to fly me onsite. I will not have more than 1 hr/day to study since I'm working 2 jobs and am behind in schoolwork. My recruiter told me I can go at whatever pace I want, but I'm worried it will be a huge red flag to ask for the interview to be scheduled for May.

Comment: @Jen  That is true.  I know the feeling on burnt out well.  How do you usually study?  An hour solid, or the oft talked about study session with a break in the middle?  Like I am really one to talk about scheduling, I am working full time on an unpaid internship, and decided to toss in Japanese 1.....I am likely going to have to retake Japanese 1 as this internship is kicking my behind.

Comment: I wish people who downvoted questions would post why.  I see this question as valid, not sure what the downers are seeing.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of ["*Is three weeks too far out to schedule a follow up meeting?*"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57105/) though with an even longer timeline. It think the OP is talking about wanting a level of preparation that should not be required even for Google, and that this is not about being unable to make time available for the interview itself; but since others disagree this should remain on-hold. Frankly, if you can't find a single day in your schedule for an interview when you're "just" a student I would assume you're not Google material.

Comment: Please don't vandalize questions, not even your own. I've rolled it back to the previous version.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, on-topic and should not have been down-voted. Or vandalized. Please reopen immediately. If it's a duplicate, identify the duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

I've experienced Google interviews in which I've delayed the interview process to ensure that I had a better crack at the job.  It was less of a matter of worrying about my circumstances and more about communicating with their recruiter and setting their expectations in the matter.

If you're in doubt, talk to your recruiter.  They are *the* authoritative source on the timeline that you have.

You won't miss your opportunity if you ask them for a bit of time, but you *would* miss it if you didn't study properly.  From every Google engineer I've talked to in and outside of the interview process, taking time to study is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 5):

Interview now. Candidates tend to overestimate what they can accomplish by slowly studying over several months.

Alternately: ask the recruiter directly how the delay will impact your application. There is no reason they would be dishonest about this.